# Custom syntax highlighting in vim for links

Tags: vim, graph, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a custom file format for graphs which looks like this:

```
node1.link1 : node2
node1.attribute1 : an_attribute_for_node1
node2.my_attribute1 : an_attribute_for_node2
```

(there is nothing special about the attributes names, an attribute is a link iff one can find its value  at the left of a dot. So `node2` is a link, because there is a line somewhere in the file that begins with `node2.<something>`).

I would like to highlight the attribute values if they are links (so I would like to highlight node2, but not `attribute_for_node1`).

Obviously, this kind of syntax highlighting cannot be based only on line wide regexp, because one needs to read the entire file to do the correct highlighting.

I already have a python parser for this kind of files (which gives a dict of dict `string -> (string -> string)`), but I don't know if python can interact with syntax highlighting in vim 7.

**EDIT**
As a clarification, the dictionary produced for this example is:

```
d = {
  'node1': {'link1' : 'node2', 'attribute1' : 'an_attribute_for_node1'},
  'node2': {'attribute2': 'an_attribute_for_node2'}
}
```

By definition, `l` is a link for node `n` if and only if:

```
d[n][l] in d
```

Names are meaningless, the format is only structure dependant, and there is no language keywords.
I would like to highlight `node2` in the first line, because it is the name for a node.

I hope it is clearer now.

Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be very straightforward, but it's a little difficult to work out exactly what your dict looks like (what is 'string'? node1? attribute1? something else?).  I have a plugin that I wrote called the [ctags highlighter](http://sites.google.com/site/abudden/contents/Vim-Scripts/ctags-highlighting) which does a fairly similar thing: it uses ctags to generate a list of keywords and then uses python to turn this into a simple vim script that highlights those keywords appropriately.

Basically, what you need to do is make your parser (or another python module that uses your parser) to generate a list of keywords (node1, node2 etc) and output them in this form (use as many per line as you like, but don't make the lines **too** long):

```
syn keyword GraphNode node1 node2
syn keyword GraphNode node3
```

Write this to a file and create an autocommand that does something like:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.myextension if filereadable('nodelist.vim') | source nodelist.vim | endif
```

Then do:

```
hi GraphNode guifg=blue
```

or whatever.  If you want more details, post a little more information about your parser or have a look at the code in [my plugin](http://sites.google.com/site/abudden/contents/Vim-Scripts/ctags-highlighting).

For more information, see

```
:help :autocmd
:help syn-keyword
:help BufEnter
:help BufNewFile
:help filereadable()
:help :source
:help :highlight
```

**Edit**

I'm still not completely sure I know what you want, but if I am understanding correctly, something like this should work:

Let's assume that your python parser is called `mypyparser.py`, it takes one argument (the current filename) and the dictionary it creates is called `MyPyDict`.  You'll obviously have to modify the script to match the actual use of your parser.  Add this script somewhere in your runtimepath (e.g. in .vimrc or in ~/.vim/ftplugin/myfiletype.vim) and then open your file and type `:HighlightNodes`.

```
" Create a command for ease of use
command! HighlightNodes call HighlightNodes()
function! HighlightNodes()
    " Run the parser to create MyPyDict
    exe 'pyfile mypyparser.py ' . expand('%:p')
    " Next block is python code (indent gone to keep python happy)
    py <<EOF
# Import the Vim interface
import vim
# Iterate through the keys in the dictionary and highlight them in Vim
for key in MyPyDict.keys():
    vim.command('syn keyword GraphNode ' + key)
endfor
EOF
    " Make sure that the GraphNode is highlighted in some colour or other
    hi link GraphNode Keyword
endfunction
```

Comment: I am sorry for not having been clear.
the syntax of the format, in pseudo(-pseudo) BNF, is
line := node '.' attribute ':' link | property
node := [a-Z]+
link := node
attribute := [a-Z]+
property := [a-Z]+

The only thing that discriminates a node from a property is that it can be the name of a node
My python dict like this is {'node1' : {'link1':'node1', 'attribute1': 'an_attribute_for_node_1'}, 'node2': {'my_attribute1' : 'an_attribute_for_node2'}}
l is a link for a node n iff d[n][l] in d
So node1 has no signification at all. In fact, the syntax is NOT keyword based. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you use keywords based on a language file, but based on parsing of the current file.  For example, in my C code, if I have a function called GetCurrentValue(), I would expect GetCurrentValue to be highlighted throughout that code, despite it not being a C keyword.  If I open a different project, I would not expect GetCurrentValue to be highlighted.  I guess what I'm asking is: "in this file specifically, should 'node2' be highlighted at the end of line 1 and the start of line 3, or just on the first line?".

Comment: I've added a more explicit example of what I mean, but if I'm still wrong, perhaps you could give a more detailed example with a sample file and the specific parts and locations you want highlighted for that file?

Comment: That will do the trick, thanks. I only want to highlight just the link, ie the node2 that is at the right of the :, but I think that with your second example I will be able to do it. Thanks !